# How can I change the character width in text editor?

Tags: text-editor, font

One day I opened Blender, and the text editor character width was diminished. It is hard to read and type on the text editor. I tried to find the menu *Paragraph > Character width*, but could not find the menu or function to solve my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open sidebar in TextEditor

[image]

and tweak Font Size in Properties tab:

[image]

Comment: I know it can change the Font Size, but I can't change the font width. The characters are still overlapped.

Comment: Is there a monospace font selected in Preferences > Interface > Text Rendering? If so try to reset with RMB.

Comment: Works like magic. Thanks.